# Does Bethsaida really not speak Universal?

Tags: peltedverse

Re-reading the beginning of *Even the Wingless*, it struck me that Bethsaida is said to not understand Universal. But she's a Galare, and Liolesa's heir. Even if she comes from one of the few Galare families that don't believe in learning Universal, how could Liolesa choose an heir with such a defect in her education? Or, having chosen such an heir, perhaps for lack of a better choice, how could she have not immediately set about correcting the deficiency? And perhaps even more to the point, how would someone who only speaks Eldren ever even conceive of leaving the planet, let alone in secret/without permission?